# Deleting a row that is not equal to another row but not considering NA's in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I Have this file:

```
Name Father1 Father2
Joe    1        1
Jan    2        2
Lion  NA       NA
Faire NA        5
jake  5        NA
Stan  3         4
Paul  1         2
```

And I would like to delete the the different fathers between Father1 and 2, except NA's, like this:

```
 Name Father1 Father2
    Joe    1        1
    Jan    2        2
    Lion  NA       NA
    Faire NA        5
    jake  5        NA
```

I tried this code but didn't work.

```
New.file=my.file[!(my.file$Father1 != my.file$Father2),]
```

And I obtained this one:

```
Name Father1 Father2
Joe    1        1
Jan    2        2
 NA   NA       NA
 NA   NA       NA
 NA   NA       NA
```

The program deleted the different rows, but replace the another ones with a NA.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this please :

```
data_not <-data[!(data$father1 != data$father2),]
data[!(data$Name %in% data_not$Name),]
```

It works when I do it with this example :

```
data <- data.table(Name = c("joe", "jan", "lion", "faire"), father1 = 
c(1,2,NA,5), father2 = c(1,2,3,4))
output :
    Name father1 father2
1:   joe       1       1
2:   jan       2       2
3:  lion      NA       3
4: faire       5       4

data_not <-data[!(data$father1 != data$father2),]
data[!(data$Name %in% data_not$Name),]

new output : 
   Name father1 father2
1:  joe       1       1
2:  jan       2       2
3: lion      NA       3
```

Tell me if it is helping you.

Comment: Worked but I needed to change a little.  Because I used this way : `data_not <-data[!(data$father1 != data$father2),]`. Please change your answer and I will accept. And thanks.